# Avoiding Tkinter OptionMenu button resizing

Tags: python, button, tkinter, optionmenu

I've the following OptionMenu:

```
self.textoprioridad = Label(self.frameTwo, text = "Prioridad: ", justify="center")
self.textoprioridad.grid(row=n, column=4)
var2 = StringVar()
menu2 = OptionMenu(self.frameTwo, var2, "Primera pieza", "Esta semana", "Normal", "Baja")
menu2.grid(row=n, column=5, ipadx=10)
var2.set("Primera pieza")
self.optionmenus_prioridad.append((menu2, var2))
```

That shows something like this:

[image]

The thing is that if I choose `Normal` from the list, the button resized and it makes smaller:
[image]

I would like to know if it's any way to keep the OptionMenu button with the initial size, like this:
[image]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Specify width by `config(width=desired-width)`:

```
menu2.config(width=20)
```

Answer (score 3):

One solution is to give the widget a specific size by specifying the `width` attribute:

```
menu2.configure(width=20)
```

Another solution is to have the widgets "stick" to the sides of their container:

```
menu2.grid(row=n, column=5, ipadx=10, sticky="ew")
```

Using the second option, the widgets can still possibly resize, but they are constrained by the size of the column they are in. If one resizes they all resize, guaranteeing they will always be uniform in size.

Answer (score 3):

Specify a `sticky` in the `grid` method so that it knows how wide to needs to be:

```
button.grid(sticky="WE")
```

This method is better than specifying a set `width` in the `grid` method becuase it means that the widget will always span the length of the column.

`sticky` is a key that shows where the widget will stick too. if you say `sticky='W'` than the widget will stick to the left of the column. By making is `EW` it will stick to the left and right, and therefore stretch it's self to the length of the column. *NOTE: it's North South East West*

Comment: A much better way... *then what?* Remember, answers may not show up in the order that you see them, so if you're referring to some other answer, you need to be more specific.